# @ControllerAdvice handler not being called from Spring Cloud custom filter

Tags: spring-boot, exception, filter, spring-cloud

I have created the following custom filter to be used for authorization in a Spring Cloud application.  Here is the `apply()` method from that filter, from which an exception is thrown should the authorization check fail:

```
@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;

        try {
            String authRequest = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(
                 Constants.SESSION_HEADER_NAME);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(authRequest, headers);
            // make REST call to authorization module
            status = restTemplate.postForEntity(authURL, entity, String.class).getStatusCode();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Something went wrong during authorization", e);
        }

        // throw an exception if anything went
        // wrong with authorization
        if (!HttpStatus.OK.equals(status)) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    };
}
```

I have defined the following `@ControllerAdvice` class to catch all exceptions thrown by the above Gateway Cloud filter:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = ResponseStatusException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(ResponseStatusException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("UNAUTHORIZED", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

What I currently observe is the following:

- The above custom filter's `ResponseStatusException` is *not* being caught by the `@ControllerAdvice` mapping method.
- Yet, throwing this exception from elsewhere in the Spring Boot application, e.g. the regular controller we use as an authentication endpoint, *is* caught by the `@ControllerAdvice` method.

For now, this is more of a nuisance than a blocker, because in fact throwing a `ResponseStatusException` from the Cloud filter with a custom error code in fact does return that error code to the caller.  But, it would be nice to handle all exceptions in a single place.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Comment: Can you also show mechanism how this filter is plugged into servlet processing chain?

Comment: @luboskrnac I don't know this, that's why I asked the question :-) ... the available documentation for Spring Cloud gateway is pretty thin, leaving the only real options as Stack Overflow, or reading the source code yourself.

Comment: Spring needs to be aware of that filter so that it can apply it. Can you show full class? Typically servlet filters are plugged into your Spring Security configuration. If this filter is being applied, there is already some mechanism in your application.

Comment: This is not a J2EE web filter, and while it may plugin to Spring Security under the hood, such implementation details are hidden from those using Spring Cloud.

Comment: Spring Cloud is just set of helpers to integrate with common cloud patterns/services. Spring Boot (with help of Spring MVC and Spring Security + **servlet container**) are handling requests. So in fact it is standard servlet filter as from J2EE world.

Comment: @luboskrnac OK, going with your comment, is there any general remedy for getting `@ControllerAdvice` to work with exceptions coming from J2EE filters?

Comment: `@ControllerAdvice` doesn't work for Spring Cloud Gateway filters.

Comment: @spencergibb Hi Spencer, thanks for reading my question.  I basically have to come this conclusion already.  Would you mind posting an answer regarding the best practice for throwing an exception from a Cloud filter?

Answer (score 1):

From [ControllerAdvice javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html):

> Classes with @ControllerAdvice can be declared explicitly as Spring beans or auto-detected via classpath scanning.

You didn't show full class for your filter, but I bet it isn't Spring Bean scanned on classpath. Typically servlet filters are explicitly plugged into Spring Security configuration. Therefore ControllerAdvice processing is ignoring it.

Comment: The Cloud filter is in the `filter` directory, which sits directly below the class containing the `@SpringBootApplication` controller.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by Filter you mean `javax.servlet.Filter`.

In that case, `@ControllerAdvice` cannot work. It is used to handle exceptions from Controllers. But you throw Exception before it can even propagate to Controller (by not calling the `chain.filter(exchange)` method.

Try throwing exceptions in controller, not in filter.

**Edit:** If you don't want to handle exceptions on `@Controller`, you must implement terminal handler in `javax.servlet.Filter` directly. That means change the incoming request' response directly like this:

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) exchange.getResponse();

// either format the response by yourself
httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
httpResponse.setHeader(...)
...

// or let populate error directly
httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```

... which is something what `@ControllerAdvice` does internally.

Comment: Interesting suggestion.  So, in this case, would the correct pattern be to just throw terminal exceptions directly from the custom Cloud filter?

Comment: Edited to answer your follow-up question.